# Tem como repetir a propriedade "animation-delay" em cada interação da animação?

Tags: html, css

A propriedade `animation-delay` só acontece apenas uma única vez na primeira interação da animação, mas após isso ela não é mais aplica no elemento.

No exemplo abaixo ao passar o mouse no `#container` a animação é aplicada no 
`#square`, mas com um atraso de `1s`:

**Exemplo:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #container:hover #square {
            animation: anima 2s linear infinite 1s;
        }

        #square {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #808080;
            position: relative;
        }

        @keyframes anima {
            0% {
                left: 0;
            }

            100% {
                left: 400px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Após esse `1s` a animação é iniciada e quando terminar, ela volta a ser executada novamente, mas nesse voltar o `animation-delay` não funciona mais. Eu gostaria que cada interação da animação a propriedade `animation-delay` funcione e não apenas na primeira interação.

**NOTA**: nesse caso eu gostaria de apenas usar *CSS*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O delay é aplicado apenas quando a animação inicia, e não no ciclo de animação em si. Então quando a animação começa tem o `delay`, mas depois que ela entra em `loop` não!

> O deslocamento do tempo, a **partir do momento em que a animação é aplicada ao elemento**, no qual a animação deve começar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas tem como resolver isso, só com CSS e matemática é claro :D. Então se a sua animação tem `2s` e vc quer um delay de `1s`, vc na verdade tem que por a animação com `3s` (2s da animação e 1s do tempo parada)

Assim, no seu `@keyframes` vc coloca a animação para começar em `33,33%`, o que corresponde a `1s` de `3s` que vc tem, pronto agora ela sempre fica `1s` parada antes de repetir o ciclo.

**Código da imagem acima:**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #container:hover #square {
            animation: anima 3s linear infinite;
        }

        #square {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: #808080;
            position: relative;
        }

        @keyframes anima {
            33.33% {
                left: 0;
            }

            100% {
                left: 400px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="square"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu! @hugocsl ótima resposta, me ajudou muito, você é o cara :) 

Comment: @joãobatista que bom que vc conseguiu pegar a ideia ai, []´s